# Unable to write the complete script onto a device on the serial port

Tags: c, linux

The script file has over 6000 bytes which is copied into a buffer.The contents of the buffer are then written to the device connected to the serial port.However the write function only returns 4608 bytes whereas the buffer contains 6117 bytes.I'm unable to understand why this happens.

```
{   
    FILE *ptr;

    long numbytes;
    int i;
    ptr=fopen("compass_script(1).4th","r");//Opening the script file

    if(ptr==NULL)
        return 1;

    fseek(ptr,0,SEEK_END);

    numbytes = ftell(ptr);//Number of bytes in the script 
    printf("number of bytes in the calibration script %ld\n",numbytes);
    //Number of bytes in the script is 6117.                      
    fseek(ptr,0,SEEK_SET);
    char writebuffer[numbytes];//Creating a buffer to copy the file

    if(writebuffer == NULL)
        return 1;

    int s=fread(writebuffer,sizeof(char),numbytes,ptr);
    //Transferring  contents into the buffer

    perror("fread");

    fclose(ptr);

    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB3",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    //Opening serial port

    speed_t baud=B115200;

    struct termios serialset;//Setting a baud rate for communication

    tcgetattr(fd,&serialset);

    cfsetispeed(&serialset,baud);
    cfsetospeed(&serialset,baud);

    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&serialset); 

    long bytesw=0;
    tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);
    printf("\nnumbytes %ld",numbytes);
    bytesw=write(fd,writebuffer,numbytes);
    //Writing the script into the  device connected to the serial port

    printf("bytes written%ld\n",bytesw);//Only 4608 bytes are written

    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I afraid no-one will be able to help you. You need to figure it out yourself

Comment: Umm.. 'O_NONBLOCK'..

Comment: Yea figured that out after I had posted the question.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, 1) code has trouble yet does not check the result of various functions. `fseek(), fread(), tcgetattr()`, and at least 4 others, etc.  Seems like that would be the first step and more efficient that posting on SO.  2) Try opening the file in binary more.  `fopen("compass_script(1).4th","rb")`

Comment: [Read the docs!](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html#RETURN_VALUE)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the specification.  When you write to a file, your process normally is blocked until the whole data is written.  And this means your process will run again only when all the data has been written to the disk buffers.  This is not true for devices, as the device driver is the responsible of determining how much data is to be written in one pass.  This means that, depending on the device driver, you'll get all data driven, only part of it, or even none at all.  That simply depends on the device, and how the driver implements its control.

On the floor, device drivers normally have a limited amount of memory to fill buffers and are capable of a limited amount of data to be accepted.  There are two policies here, the driver can block the process until more buffer space is available to process it, or it can return with a partial write only.

It's your program resposibility to accept a partial read and continue writing the rest of the buffer, or to pass back the problem to the client module and return only a partial write again.  This approach is the most flexible one, and is the one implemented everywhere.  Now you have a reason for your partial write, but the ball is on your roof, you have to decide what to do next.

Also, be careful, as you use `long` for the `ftell()` function call return value and `int` for the `fwrite()` function call... Although your amount of data is not huge and it's not probable that this values cannot be converted to `long` and `int` respectively, the return type of both calls is `size_t` and `ssize_t` resp. (like the `speed_t` type you use for the baudrate values)  `long` can be 32bit and `size_t` a 64bit type.

The best thing you can do is to ensure the whole buffer is written by some code snippet like the next one:

```
char *p = buffer;
while (numbytes > 0) {
    ssize_t n = write(fd, p, numbytes);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("write");
        /* driver signals some error */
        return 1;
    }
    /* writing 0 bytes is weird, but possible, consider putting
     * some code here to cope for that possibility. */
    /* n >= 0 */
    /* update pointer and numbytes */
    p += n;
    numbytes -= n;
}
/* if we get here, we have written all numbytes */
```

Comment: Was about to post that code snippet by myself. Good answer. +1.

Comment: Yes, that was very helpful.